# Transform GeoJSON shape with 2 requirements

Tags: geojson, shapely, union

We have this shape in GeoJSON:

https://gist.github.com/panchicore/0324b0e366211c3d907b1c42f54db9c9

And the expected output is:

1. Outer side (frontiers) sticks to its country frontiers (given the country GeoJSON) https://gist.github.com/panchicore/6cf981147b235f67dec514ac35fda2a1)
2. Inner side, it softens, it makes the lines curvier

Which would be the best way/pipeline to get this combo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to open both GeoJSON in QGIS and familiarize yourself with Processing Toolbox algorithms "Intersection", "Diffference". With both, you will be able to crop at the country frontier and get 3 polygons like below (the selected one in yellow can be removed). You can merge them with "Merge vector layer" algorithm. The output will look like the following:

[image]

Then, use "Polygons to lines" algorithm. Split lines using "Edit" > "Split Features" (you need also to use snapping options to be precise). Then, you can select the shared feature (line in the middle). You can then use "Smooth" algorithm (be aware that you need to use it only on selected feature. When you are happy with smoothing line, you can then use "Polygonize" algorithm. I've also made some cleaning by merging 2 polygons artifacts resulting from intersection/difference due to error in your second drawing due to overlap on the border with Mali. At the end, I got two polygons like below.

[image: Smoothed polygons]

The resulting GeoJSON can be found at https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/207d4ca5cb9d116c81752a3c17d6c24b

PS: each time I mentioned an algorithm, it's one in the Processing Toolbox